# Problem in Building mplsh-run in lshkit

Tags: c++, open-source, include, linker, gsl

been trying out this for quite some time but 
I'm still unable to built mplsh-run from lshkit

Not sure if this would help to explain my situation during the 
building process

```
 /tmp/cc17kth4.o: In function `lshkit::MultiProbeLshRecallTable::reset(lshkit::MultiProbeLshModel, unsigned int, double, double)':
mplsh-run.cpp:(.text._ZN6lshkit24MultiProbeLshRecallTable5resetENS_18MultiProbeLshModelEjdd[lshkit::MultiProbeLshRecallTable::reset(lshkit::MultiProbeLshModel, unsigned int, double, double)]+0x230): undefined reference to `lshkit::MultiProbeLshModel::recall(double) const'
/tmp/cc17kth4.o: In function `void lshkit::MultiProbeLshIndex<unsigned int>::query_recall<lshkit::TopkScanner<lshkit::Matrix<float>::Accessor, lshkit::metric::l2sqr<float> > >(float const*, float, lshkit::TopkScanner<lshkit::Matrix<float>::Accessor, lshkit::metric::l2sqr<float> >&) const':
mplsh-run.cpp:(.text._ZNK6lshkit18MultiProbeLshIndexIjE12query_recallINS_11TopkScannerINS_6MatrixIfE8AccessorENS_6metric5l2sqrIfEEEEEEvPKffRT_[void lshkit::MultiProbeLshIndex<unsigned int>::query_recall<lshkit::TopkScanner<lshkit::Matrix<float>::Accessor, lshkit::metric::l2sqr<float> > >(float const*, float, lshkit::TopkScanner<lshkit::Matrix<float>::Accessor, lshkit::metric::l2sqr<float> >&) const]+0x2c4): undefined reference to `lshkit::MultiProbeLsh::genProbeSequence(float const*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >&, unsigned int) const'
/tmp/cc17kth4.o: In function `void lshkit::MultiProbeLshIndex<unsigned int>::query<lshkit::TopkScanner<lshkit::Matrix<float>::Accessor, lshkit::metric::l2sqr<float> > >(float const*, unsigned int, lshkit::TopkScanner<lshkit::Matrix<float>::Accessor, lshkit::metric::l2sqr<float> >&)':
mplsh-run.cpp:(.text._ZN6lshkit18MultiProbeLshIndexIjE5queryINS_11TopkScannerINS_6MatrixIfE8AccessorENS_6metric5l2sqrIfEEEEEEvPKfjRT_[void lshkit::MultiProbeLshIndex<unsigned int>::query<lshkit::TopkScanner<lshkit::Matrix<float>::Accessor, lshkit::metric::l2sqr<float> > >(float const*, unsigned int, lshkit::TopkScanner<lshkit::Matrix<float>::Accessor, lshkit::metric::l2sqr<float> >&)]+0x4a): undefined reference to `lshkit::MultiProbeLsh::genProbeSequence(float const*, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >&, unsigned int) const'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the command that i used to built mplsh-run is 
       g++ -I./lshkit/include -L/usr/lib -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas -lboost_program_options-mt mplsh-run.cpp

Do you guys have any clue on how I could solve this?

Comment: hey watch your language in your question titles!  (that's a joke.) (sorry i don't know anything about this question, just wanted to make a joke.)  (good luck.)

Comment: haha, thanks =) i really that I wrote something wrong in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the .cpp file as the first argument.

```
g++ mplsh-run.cpp -I./lshkit/include -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas -lboost_program_options-mt
```

Also try with different permutations of -lm -lgsl and -lgslcblas

Comment: I need to include in the lshkit.a

Comment: g++ mplsh-run.cpp -I./lshkit/include -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas -lboost_program_options-mt /usr/lib/liblshkit.a

Finally able to compile =) Thanks a million baol